# Does Google Assistant driving mode run on old cars made for Android Auto?

Tags: android-auto

We have an ~3 years old Opel car which was made for Android Auto.

It always worked using an USB cable only (not over Bluetooth).

Bluetooth is also supported but only for making phone calls and not for Android Auto.

Now I heard that Android Auto was replaced by Google Assistant driving mode.

I cannot get it to work over cable nor over Bluetooth.

I hardly assume my car does not support the new Google Assistant driving mode.

Can someone confirm Google Assistant driving mode only runs on new cars?

Comment: Can you describe more about your automobile, like Year of manufacture and the model.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt Opel Karl 2019